# Looking for the Spring profile in a component class always returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

For some context:

The component needs to do logic based on the current environment. Since there is no way to set the environment manually, a lot of the @Properties annotations won't work - setting the properties file is just not flexible enough for our needs. However, when I try to pull environment details into my component class, nothing seems to work! Examples make it look so easy but mine always returns null. Could I be missing something below the hood of Spring that would cause this? Here is what I've tried:

Using Resource, and it's logs:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class compClass {
    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    public void map(DtoObj dto){
        log.info("RUN PROFILE IS: {}", env.getActiveProfiles());
    }
}
```

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null`
   `at com.demo.Com.map(CompClass.java:22) ~[classes/:na]`

Using Autowire, and it's logs:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CompClass {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public void map(DtoObj dto){
        log.info("RUN PROFILE IS: {}", env.getActiveProfiles());
    }
}
```

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null`
   `at com.demo.Com.map(CompClass.java:22) ~[classes/:na]`

@Value with environment and it's logs:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CompClass {
    @Value("#{environment.activeProfiles}")
    private String[] profiles;

    public void map(DtoObj dto){
        log.info("RUN PROFILE IS: {}", profiles);
    }
}
```

`RUN PROFILE IS: null`

@Value with properties path and it's logs

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CompClass {
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String[] profiles;

    public void map(DtoObj dto){
        log.info("RUN PROFILE IS: {}", profiles);
    }
}
```

`RUN PROFILE IS: null`

here is what I can share of properties under java/main/resources:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: namnam
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

I am runing this on IntelliJ using this VM:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

I have my properties file in the java/main/resources directory, and we're able to use it's other properties in the code. What about this have I messed up?

Comment: can you show the `properties` file ? and also still i don't get your issue, you mean `profiles` is null always and `env.getActiveProfiles()` is null ? and also can you add the logs

Comment: Yes, I've updated my OP with your requested edits. Is this more descriptive? The calls I make always return null so attempting to use methods on those nulls is throwing NullPointerException (as one would expect).

Comment: Your second approach `Autowired` the `Environment` looks good to me, and i do also see `Environment` is null, so which mean you are doing something wrong  while using `compClass` class some where, if it is possible can you show the code how are you calling `compClass` class method or injecting `compClass` into another bean

Comment: Unfortunately I've shared the extent that I can of the code without violating certain agreements. This CompClass is a mapper. The Controller calls out to a batch job which reads, processes, the writes. That batch job is the bean. During the process step, our Processor class reaches out to a mapper - Our Mapper Here :) Am I too far outside of the spring context for environment to have any values?

Comment: Oh, dear - in my Config, I have beans for my batch job, my item reader and my item mapper (different mapper, not Our Mapper Here), but not my processor. I wonder if added Processor bean for my batch configuration class could help?

Comment: you can try that, but i can't assure until i see more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let me clarify something:
I do not suggest placing `@Configuration` on your business objects (beans). classes annotated with `@Configuration` are meant to be a tool for definitions of other beans. They usually look like:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public SomeBean someBean() {
      return new SomeBean();
   }

      @Bean
   public AnotherBean anotherBean() {
      return new AnotherBean();
   }
}
```

In this example, `SomeBean` and `AnotherBean` are "business" objects. This works as an alternative to putting `@Service/@Component` on these classes, and in any case you never should put `@Configuration` on them.

### Now regarding the question and proposed solutions:

In a nutshell, you can inject the environment like this:

```
@Service
public class EnvChecker {


    private final Environment env;

    public EnvChecker(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(env); // this is not null
    }
}
```

If you want to activate the profile, use `--spring.profiles.active=dev` as a "Program Argument" text field in intelliJ (-D won't work)

Although this answers the question, since its real project, let me express some thoughts that may influence the actual code you'll write at the end.

IMO: its not a good idea to make your business **code** (I mean at the level of coding) dependent on different environments, what if tomorrow you'll add yet another environment (test, qa, integration, production 1, production 2 - you name it). This logic will become unmaintainable.

To address this, spring traditionally used profiles.

Instead of using `if-condition` in the code depending on the injected environment you can create two beans and activate with different profiles:

Example:

You probably have something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private  Environment env; // lets assume it works right
    
    public void doSomething() {

      if(env.getActiveProfiles() contains "dev") { // its a pseudo code, not real java, but still...
         doFoo(); // some code
      }
      else {
        doBar(); // another piece of code
      }
    }    
}
```

So The first suggestion using profiles is:

```
@Service
@Profile("dev")
public class DevBean {
   public void doSomething() {
     doFoo();
   }
}


@Service
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdBean {
   public void doSomething() {
     doBar();
   }
}
```

This approach is better because the business code will be easier to read and maintain, on the other hand, there is still a code that depends on profile state.
However there is another solution that I like even better and can recommend:

The idea is **"treat" a profile as a series of business features** that can be enabled or disabled. This makes sense because profiles by themselves usually denote the environment but the project is always comprised of business features.

So, lets assume that your code implements the feature X that deals with database connectivity (for the sake of example). You want to disable the database in the development environment and would like to work "in-memory".

So in the terms of feature  that the system provides you can define the following:

`feature.X.mode=database / in-memory`

Then you can configure the `dev` profile with "in-memory" property and the default value (the rest of profiles) can be "database":

```
application-dev.yml:

feature:
  X: 
    mode: "in-memory"
```

```
application.yml:
feature:
  X: 
    mode: "database" # or you can even omit the definition, leaving the default to be the "database"
```

Now the beans can be defined in a similar manner to the previous technique but now you won't depend anymore on the profile, and instead will depend on the availability of the business feature:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.X.mode", havingValue="in-memory")
public class DevBean {
   public void doSomething() {
     doFoo();
   }
}


@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.X.mode", havingValue="database", matchIfMissing=true) // the last parameter guarantees that the bean will be loaded even if there is no configuration at all
public class ProdBean {
   public void doSomething() {
     doBar();
   }
}
```

Now finally you don't have the "environment dependent code".

The last small tip is what if you have several beans like this (service/components).
In this case you can define the "stereotype annotation" (`@FeatureXService`) or use Java Configuration (class annotated with `@Configuration`) and place that `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation only once.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is working fine with me I hope it will be useful to you.

```
@Configuration
public class CompClass {

private final Environment env;

public CompClass (Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}

public void map(DtoObj dto){
    log.info("RUN PROFILE IS: {}", env.getActiveProfiles());
}

public void doSomethingBasedOnSpeceficProfile() {
 if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
    // do something if the profile is what you want
  } else {
        // do something else
  }
}}
```

Comment: I am working on an enterprise project, I can't call it ClassName1. Could you clarify what this Config's purpose is, so I can know if I have a more applicable name or maybe can put bean in already existing class?

Comment: You can rename it whatever you want -actually I rename it myself before submitting the code- @ configuration is just another way of wiring for classes that are used to configure your application -a sub type of @ component- and the bean method I added inside the class is just to illustrate how you can use it

Comment: So try to add @ configuration and use constructor injection, it may work

Comment: What is the machine service doing here, what does it tell Spring about my project? What does CerebralIntegration mean and what is that intended for? I don't understand what the CMachineService and buildMachineService are doing? Is this all pieces relevant to me or am I misunderstanding?

Would something like this typically go in with other spring beans? I don't want to create brand new config class for on bean in a large project for no reason, so does this group with the others?

Comment: But this needs to be a component - can it be a component and a configuration?

Comment: I edited my answer removing irrelevant parts. you can annotated your class with @ configuration and still get the same behavior of @ component since @ configuration is just a subtype of @ component, but anyway try it first with @ component if it doesn't work try it with @ configuration, If both didn't work then for sure there is something wong about how you configured your profiles